# Import Windows MySQL dump on a Debian Linux server

Tags: mysql, linux, mysqldump, windows, mysql-5.7

I created a test database on a Windows computer with MySQL 5.7 and filled it with many data records.
Now I created a database dump with mysqldump and wanted to import it on my server (Debian Jessie, also MySQL 5.7).

During the import of the dump I received several error messages, which were not helpful.
Therefore I looked at the dump file with the nano editor and found out that the content cannot be displayed correctly:

```
��-^@-^@ ^@M^@y^@S^@Q^@L^@ ^@d^@u^@m^@p^@ ^@1^@0^@.^@1^@3^@ ^@ ^@D^@i^@s^@t^@r^$
^@
^@-^@-^@
^@
^@-^@-^@ ^@H^@o^@s^@t^@:^@ ^@l^@o^@c^@a^@l^@h^@o^@s^@t^@ ^@ ^@ ^@ ^@D^@a^@t^@a^$
^@
...
```

But if I open the dump under Windows in e.g. Notepad++, everything can be displayed perfectly.

So I thought about an error during the FTP upload. However, if I transfer a file from Windows to Linux and then transfer it back, the new file will still be readable under Windows, but not under Linux.

Can anyone give me a hint?
Thanks!

Little update:
This is how I made the dump:

```
.\mysqldump.exe -u root --databases m_data > D:\m_data_dump.sql
```

Update 2:
I also tried exporting with explicit charset:

```
.\mysqldump.exe -u root --default-character-set=utf8mb4 --databases m_data > D:\m_data_dump.sql
```

And imprted with:

```
mysql -u root -p --default-character-set=utf8mb4 < m_data_dump.sql
```

But sam result.

Comment: Encodings do not match. Use proper charset/collation on all export-import steps.

Comment: Hi Akina, thank your for your message. I already tried with an explicit given charset (see Update 2). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 1) Specify charset while exporting, not only while importing. 2) Check that system/server/connection/database/tables/fields charsets are synced. 3) Test separate copying: structure via mysqldump, data via SELECT INTO OUTFILE / LOAD DATA INFILE.

Answer (score 3):

The contents of the dump file you show appear to be UTF16 - this may be the result of the redirect operator on Windows (particularly if you're using PowerShell).

To avoid the Windows shell redirection operator interfering with the encoding/formatting of data emitted by the mysqldump program, use the --result-file=filename when dumping.

See the MySQL docs for this command line option at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_result-file

Comment: Thank you very much, that sounds very plausible, I will try it out.